# jQuery hover box close issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am in the process of modifying a drupal 7 website for a client and have come across a problem trying to get a jQuery Login box working correctly as required.

You can see a working version of the site at http://www.tztesting.com

The idea is that when a user hovers over the Login link a login box should appear. When the user leaves the hover or submits the Login form the box must close.

I can get the box to open with no problem when I hover on the Login link and I can get the box to close when I leave the box without completing the form. The problem I am having is the box completing before the form is filled out. As far as I can tell this is happening because I am not using the `mouseleave` event correctly to close the box.

Here is my JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    jQuery('ul.menu.nav.navbar-nav.secondary li.last.leaf').hover(function() {
        var $loginContainer = jQuery(loginContainer);
        $loginContainer.fadeIn();
    }, function() {
        jQuery('.login-overlay-container').mouseleave(function(){
            var $loginContainer = jQuery(loginContainer);
            $loginContainer.fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

The horrible looking selector is because of the way Drupal builds its menu structure.

In the html there is a block of text inside a class called login-overlay-container.

I would appreciate it if someone could show me a way to allow the user to fill out and submit the form without the `mouseleave` event from firing and calling the `fadeout` function

Comment: Without the jQuery('.login-overlay-container').mouseleave(function(){ the box simply closes when you move the hover away from the Login Link. I need the box to remain open so it can be completed and when you enter the box you are no longer hovering over the link that opened the box

Comment: you mean to say that the problem is, if user trying to enter an email address and if by mistaken mouse gets moved away from form, then form is closing?

Comment: As soon as you try to enter anything in either field on the form the box gets closed before you finish entering details or clicking the submit button

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with below approach:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    jQuery('ul.menu.nav.navbar-nav.secondary li.last.leaf').hover(function() {
        var $loginContainer = jQuery(loginContainer);
        $loginContainer.fadeIn();
    }, function() {
       jQuery('.login-overlay-container').mouseleave(function(){
            var hasFocus = false;
            jQuery('.login-overlay-container input').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":focus"))
                {
                    hasFocus = true;
                }
            });
            if(!hasFocus){
                var $loginContainer = jQuery(loginContainer);
                $loginContainer.fadeOut();
            }
       });
    });
});
```

In this approach we are checking whether any of `textfield` or `checkbox` has the focus. If any of them has `focus` then don't close the overlay otherwise close it.

Comment: oh..great... thats awesome...`:)`!